# Android/Java: Fragment instantiating causes memory leak?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, memory-leaks

My `MainActivity` has a `Drawer` and instantiates a new `Fragment`, depending on the clicked `MenuItem` (based on [this tutorial](http://chrisrisner.com/Using-Fragments-with-the-Navigation-Drawer-Activity)).

I monitored the **memory**, which is **slightly increasing** on every Fragment change and I worry, that `fragmentClass.newInstance()` is not the right way.

```
// MainActivity
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();
    Fragment fragment = null;
    Class fragmentClass = null;
    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        fragmentClass = CameraFragment.class;
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
        fragmentClass = GalleryFragment.class;
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {
        fragmentClass = SlideshowFragment.class;
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {
        fragmentClass = ManageFragment.class;
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
        fragmentClass = ShareFragment.class;
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {
        fragmentClass = SendFragment.class;
    }

    try {
        fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.layout_main, fragment).commit();
}
```

I would expect something like:

```
// Pseudocode
if (fragmentManager.instanceExists(fragmentClass)) {
    // load instantiated fragment
} else {
    // newInstance()
}
```

How could I avoid memory leaks or is this even related?

Thank you!

Comment: Just an observation, `fragmentClass = CameraFragment.class`  could be written like `fragment = CameraFragment.newInstance()`.  Its a bit cleaner and you likely wont need a try catch block anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Practically, there is no problems in that code. Things you can optimize are:

1. Reworking `Fragment#instantiate()` method (check [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#instantiate(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String)))
2. Caching instances in something like `Map` in order not to create the new one every time you navigate through the drawer

Also, you can check if fragment exists in FragmentManager using `FragmentManager#findFragmentById()` or `FragmentManager#findFragmentByTag()`